# How to use AjaxData with Bjornblog Store Locator

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to connect my store locator (by bjorn at https://github.com/bjorn2404/jQuery-Store-Locator-Plugin) to an object where I've pulled in location data with an XMLHttpRequest.

Can't get it to work. I created a smaller object manually with some of his sample data and couldn't get that to work either.

The documentation just says:
property - ajaxData ; default - null ; description - Allows custom data to be sent with the AJAX request. Set the setting to an object with your properties and values.

...but I must be confused on what 'setting to an object' means.

Here's what I have in my script:

---

```js
            let practiceData = 
                {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Chipotle Minneapolis",
                "lat": "44.947464",
                "lng": "-93.320826",
                "category": "Restaurant",
                "address": "3040 Excelsior Blvd",
                "address2": "",
                "city": "Minneapolis",
                "state": "MN",
                "postal": "55416",
                "phone": "612-922-6662",
                "web": "http://www.chipotle.com",
                "hours1": "Mon-Sun 11am-10pm",
                "hours2": "",
                "hours3": "",
                "featured": "",
                "features": "",
                "date": "10/17/18",
                "formattedaddress":"3040 Excelsior Blvd, Minneapolis MN 55416"
                };

              console.log(practiceData);  
              console.log('end practice data');

            $(function() {
                $('#bh-sl-map-container').storeLocator({
                    slideMap : true,
                    dataType: 'json',                  
/*                    dataLocation: '/assets/js/theme/map/locations.json',*/
                    ajaxData: practiceData,
                    fullMapStart: true,
                    infowindowTemplatePath: '/assets/js/theme/map/templates/infowindow-description.html',
                    listTemplatePath: '/assets/js/theme/map/templates/location-list-description.html'

                });
            });
```

---

There's no console errors and nothing shows on the page. If I connect it back to the default data file, the map shows, so I know it's a problem with the data connection.

I'm sure this is something dumb, but my head hurts, lol. Ideas?

Comment: `ajaxData: practiceData`

Comment: As above; you're just padding he literal string "practiceData" and not the object :-(

Comment: I tried it both ways with the same result unfortunately >>

                    ajaxData: practiceData,

Answer (score 2):

ajaxData must be a kind of query params like this.

ajaxData: {"name" : "john", "country" : "US"} ( http://localhost/?name=john&country=US )

And *dataType* should be 'json' and *dataLocation* would be url of action.

```
{ 
 ... 
    ajaxData: {"name" : "john", "country" : "US"},
    dataType: 'json',
    dataLocation: '/v2/forum/', 
 ... 
}
```

Hope this would be helpful for you!
Regards